# Handle onFailure method in Retrofit with Coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Kotlin Coroutines to work with Retrofit for API call. However, there is an issue with request to API when there is no internet connection and the app is always crashing without any proper error log in console. Please help me out !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Use this code
Handle the error with try..catch

```
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
            val response = RetrofitInstance.api.getAllPost()
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    //Do something with response e.g show to the UI.
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: ${response.code()}")
                }
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Exception ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Ooops: Something else went wrong")
            }
        }
```

Source:
https://android.jlelse.eu/kotlin-coroutines-and-retrofit-e0702d0b8e8f